# SVG - preserveAspectRatio="none" not applying

Tags: html, svg

I have a simple SVG that i would like to stretch to fill its container without preserving aspect ratio. No matter what I seem to do the SVG seems to be preserving the aspect ratio, which I believe I have turned off in the SVG file. It just never wants to stretch to the full width of the container. What exactly is going wrong here? Thank you!

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg 
version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="100%" 
height="100%"
preserveAspectRatio="none" >

<polygon points="480.4,200 0,200 0,0 480.4,0 599.9,100 " fill="#E1E1E1"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.issue-name {
    background-image:url(../img/IS-arrow.svg);
    padding-left:1rem !important;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="large-11 small-10 columns text-center issue-name">
      <h5 class="vertical-center">PLC Adjustments for Young Producers</h5>
 </div>
```

Result:

[Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4wDV.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

`preserveAspectRatio` does nothing if your SVG doesn't have a `viewBox`.

It is `viewBox` which tells the renderer how big the contents of your SVG are, so it knows how much to scale by.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove width and height from svg and add viewBox

example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg 
version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
viewBox="0 0 5.8208332 15.9"
preserveAspectRatio="none"
preserveAspectRatio="none" >

<polygon points="480.4,200 0,200 0,0 480.4,0 599.9,100 " fill="#E1E1E1"/>
</svg>
```